# Makefile - Subst - not replacing variable

Tags: linux, make

I am trying to run the following `subst` command to replace one string `/var/jenkins_home` with another `/srv/jenkins-slave-1/data` so that the value  in `HOST_LOG_DIR` changes from `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ts_myapp_testing_integration-tests` to 
`/srv/jenkins-slave-1/data/workspace/ts_myapp_testing_integration-tests`

but when I run the makefile target `substtest` the value of `HOST_LOG_FILE` remains unchanged (please see screenshot).

```
WORKSPACE               := "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ts_myapp_testing_integration-tests"
JENKINS_HOME            := "/var/jenkins_home"
JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH  := "/srv/jenkins-slave-1/data"
HOST_LOG_DIR            :=  $(subst $(JENKINS_HOME),$(JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH),$(WORKSPACE))

.PHONY: substtest, print_env

substtest: print_env

print_env:
    @echo "WORKSPACE is ${WORKSPACE}"
    @echo "JENKINS_HOME is ${JENKINS_HOME}"
    @echo "JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH is ${JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH}"
    @echo "HOST_LOG_DIR is ${HOST_LOG_DIR}"][1]][1]
```

[image]

The strange thing is when I replace `$(JENKINS_HOME)` with the actual path value `/var/jenkins_home` i.e.

`HOST_LOG_DIR           :=  $(subst /var/jenkins_home,$(JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH),$(WORKSPACE))`

then it works as expected,

[image]

I need  to fix this so that it works without the hard-coded substitution.

Comment: use **call** function to expand the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> JENKINS_HOME            := "/var/jenkins_home"
> ```

You should **not** quote the variable values in Makefiles. This is not shell, the quotes are not special in any way and are not removed.

```
WORKSPACE               := /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ts_myapp_testing_integration-tests
JENKINS_HOME            := /var/jenkins_home
JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH  := /srv/jenkins-slave-1/data
HOST_LOG_DIR            :=  $(subst $(JENKINS_HOME),$(JENKINS_HOME_HOST_PATH),$(WORKSPACE))
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response and explanation - that worked.