# shell saying "not found" for a command within a makefile

Tags: shell, make, command-not-found

When defining a **command** as a constant **within a Makefile**:

```
MY_COMMANDLINE="prog arg1 arg2"
```

and using this constant later to get the command invoked, you could get:

```
/bin/sh: prog arg1 arg2: not found
```

although prog definitely exists. 
Explicitly giving the whole path of `prog` does not help.

---

There are other questions regarding shell saying "**not found**" (e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there?newreg=efc98d3e21f54520baa1f9f6d158cf45) or [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43481/file-not-found-for-file-which-is-there?noredirect=1&lq=1)). By linking this question others may find this possible cause easier.

Comment: Related to the issue of quoting values in Makefiles: [Makefile - Subst - not replacing variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523067)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike e.g. in shell scripts the quotes become part of the string and get transferred to the shell, which obviously then searches for the whole path incl. all spaces.

Defining the command line without quotes:

```
MY_COMMANDLINE=prog arg1 arg2
```

works.